# JSON RPC 2.0: Do Extra Fields on Request Objects Violate Specification?

Tags: json, rpc, specifications, json-rpc

I am writing a JSON RPC conform js library. Are clients allowed by the specification to add custom fields (e.g. `headers`) along the `params` field to `Request` objects?

E.g.

```
{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "subtract", "params": [42, 23], "headers": { "original-client": 12 }, "id": 1}
```

The spec (https://www.jsonrpc.org/specification#request_object) does not mention anything about adding additional fields.

Does my library violate the spec if it does add an `header` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same question here. (I want to add user auth info / message signature...)

You are right in that the [Specification](https://www.jsonrpc.org/specification) does not mention anything about additional fields. So legally-speaking, if it is not forbidden, it is allowed.

On the other hand, I found at least one reference implementation here: [www.simple-is-better.org/rpc/jsonrpc.py](https://www.simple-is-better.org/rpc/jsonrpc.py), which will hit you with an exception if a decoded message contains extra fields. This code is from one of the authors of the JSON-RPC 2.0 specs, Roland Köbler.

So, YMMV.

- If your library is only an internal building block for a proprietary system, go ahead.
- If you need to interface with other JSON-RPC implementations, test each one.
- If the library is intended for public use, don't do it.

**Edit: I solved this using the following protocol:**

- Before the "payload" message, send a standard-compliant notification with method `"rpc.secinfo"`. (The `rpc.` prefix is per-spec reserved for extensions)
- The `"params"` field contains whatever metadata applies (e.g. username, signature)
- Example: `{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "rpc.secinfo", "params": {"user":"root", "signature":"0xDEADBEEF"}}<DELIM><payload><DELIM>`
- If header data is empty, No special method is pretended (i.e. behaves exactly like standard json-rpc).

The receiver can decode the header message just like any other call, and just needs to apply (check sig, whatever) the header onto the following message.

Discussion:

- allows framing without touching payload
- allows decoding the header without decoding payload
- allows using byte-payload as is, particularly allows encrypted+literal payload to coexist (however encrypted payload breaks JSON-RPC compat!)
- "Unaware" receiver: will throw the rpc.secinfo calls away silently or loudly, but is able to operate. Missing ID indicates a notification, i.e. receiver will not send response back per JSON-RPC spec.
- "Unaware" sender: Received messages are valid, no-header messages.

Feel free to reuse this protocol, but please credit this SO answer.

Comment: Thanks! I already decided to not include headers and just use prefixed param fields. This however is problematic with implementations that expect `params` to be an array...

Comment: Expanded the answer with the solution I settled on.